# Brand new SP 2013 Farm - How to move a site collection from 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, migration, move

I have a brand new SP 2013 farm (3 WFE, 1 APP, 1 DB). I did not do migration from 2010 to 2013 like many articles suggest. The new SP 2013 farm is on a different domain (DomainCisco). I dont want to go through farm upgrade from 2010 to 2013.

The idea is to migrate each site collection as needed. So I have a Sales Site collection with it's own Content DB. I tried various way to do this but nothing is working. (take a 2010 sql backup, restore it to sql 2012 db, sp-mount, etc.).

Any idea or good article that I can follow to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Their are two options to migrate the site collections.

1. Using the 3rd party tools i.e. sharegate, metalogix etc. Easy but expensive( cost you money).
2. Database upgrade. which you tried.

   - You need to move the site collection into own content DB( which u already did)
   - You have to run the test-spcontentDatabase against that db to make sure nothing bad which can fail the upgrade.
   - Take the backup of the DB from SP 2010.
   - Restore it on 2013 farm's SQL server
   - Mount the DB to the Web App.
   - make sure you have the root level site collection in that web app. If sale site collection is not root level.

If you still facing the issue then please share the error so that we can tell u further.

Comment: Waqas: http://inside2013.cbasco.com is our web application for sp 2013. the sales site is under different managed path http://inside2013.cbasco.com/sites/sales

Comment: do you have the root level site collection in that web app(inside2013.cbasco.com? what error u are getting?

Comment: Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name <contentdbname> -DatabaseServer <databaseservername> -WebApplication <webappurl>  -confirm:$false
mout is good - no error
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase <contentdbname> | Format-Table -Property Url, ID
get-spsite - returns nothing, thus i can't run the set-spsite code
Set-SPSite -Identity <IDreturnedabove> -Url <urlofhostnamedsitecollection>

Comment: I got the site id from allsites table but set-spsite gives me following error. cannot find an spsite object with id or url. the url path has added managed path. in 2010 http://intranet.../sales but 2013 it will be http://intranet../sites/sales

Comment: I am little lost...lets do from basic...Create a root level site colelction in your web app( root level "/" )...after that you upgrade the database....IF their is error or issue please share the screen shot.

Comment: root level site collection is already created. All I need to do is move a site collection from 2010 to 2013.

Comment: ok...But what happen when you run the mount-db command

Comment: mount-db seemed to be working and i can see the db through central admin

Comment: ok, then what is the issue? If DB is working fine?

Comment: Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase ... does not return anything. even if i get the site id from the content db directory the set-spsite does not work. see error i posted earlier "cannot find an spsite object with id or url

Comment: sp-mount finally worked. What I was doing is to change the Database name to something else on the target. I guess I will do the clean up after the upgrade.